# Using R to create a dummy variable by quantile using the survey package. Trouble with findInterval function

Tags: r, survey, quantile, weighted

I'm currently working with public use microdata that requires survey weighting, thus I've gotten fairly familiar with the survey package and srvyr for summary statistics.

I am trying to figure out a way to create an indicator variable for each observation in a survey object datatable which corresponds to that observation's quantile when using the quantile function. For instance, I might want to create a dummy for each observation according to the observation's quantile when calculating for "height".

I found an example of what I'm trying to do here:

[Compute quantiles incorporating Sample Design (Survey package)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167390/compute-quantiles-incorporating-sample-design-survey-package/32173435#32173435?newreg=fff12eeff2de4d59b20af4738ea49da6)

When following the steps provided in the answer,

```
data(api)

dclus1 <- svydesign(id=~dnum, weights=~pw, data=apiclus1, fpc=~fpc)
data(api)
a <- svyquantile(~api00, design = dclus1, quantiles = seq(0, 1, by=0.1), method = "linear", ties="rounded")

dclus1 <- update( dclus1 , qtile = factor( findInterval( api00 , a ) ) )
```

I get this returned :

```
Error in findInterval(api00, a) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I cannot seem to get findInterval to work on the survey quantile list object generated. From documentation for findInterval, it seems it wants a numeric object or vector. Is there a way to ammend this answer provided to get what I need? Am I missing something ?

Comment: Without sample data it's difficult to help you, but why are you working with list columns? Is there any way to unnest said columns so your code runs?

Comment: @elemn when i put `library(survey)` at the top of your script and `svymean(~qtile,dclus1)` at the bottom, it runs without error.  would it be possible for you to edit your question so it shows each step exactly on a fresh console?  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Further to @juan-c 's cmomment, I decided to pull out the quantile information I calculated via

```r
j = a$[1:4]
```

In order to do :

```r
dclus1 <- update( dclus1 , qtile = factor( findInterval( api00 , j) ) )
```

Which solved my problem.